# Is it possible to use batch scripting to retrieve Windows Server Group Policy Value?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, group-policy

Is there any batch command that will allow me to retrieve the value of the particular group policy in Windows server? Some thing like gpedit.msc did, but I want it in command line cause I want to convert those value to the format that I want.

Example: If I open gpedit.msc, then I navigate to Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment\Restore files and directories then I can get the value of this policy.

Any ways in batch scripting can get me to this path and capture the value?

Comment: `gpresult` gives all info on what is set (if absent not set to anything). It outputs normal command line (on multiple lines per entry - so useless), XML, and HTML.

Comment: Oh I see, this one I can't customise the result to the format I need. Thanks you for your reply.

Comment: I want something like REG.EXE QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\WdiSystemHost /V Start and I will get result like this HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\WdiSystemHost
    Start    REG_DWORD    0x3 
This one is just for registry, but I now I want group policy value. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

It need debugging. This is searching for *MemCheckBoxInRunDlg*.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set flag=n
for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%A in ('gpresult /z') do (
If !flag!==y echo %%A & set flag=n
Echo %%A |findstr /i /c:"memcheck">nul 2>&1
If errorlevel 0 if not errorlevel 1 set flag=y
)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I just tested the code. It doesn't work for me. I get this two line errors The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect. in command prompt. Thank you.